# ¿Cómo hacer un "HAVING" en una consulta linq c#?

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

Tengo un checkbox donde envio los datos al controller para hacer la consulta en linq donde quiero hacer un having pero no lo puedo lograr obtener, me envia la lista con 0 y otros valores, quiero solo que aparezca cuando sea > 0.

Asi mismo cuando quiero agregar otros datos al select me indica que fc no esta dento del contexto,

mi query es este:

```
select c_prestamo, d_preanexo , c_factura , sum(n_cximp) as Suma
from t_cxc
group by c_factura, c_prestamo, d_preanexo
having sum(n_cximp) <> 0
```

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewFact(List<LstReportes> model)
    {
        foreach (LstReportes item in model)
        {

            if (item.isChecked == true)
            {

                var fact2 = (from fc in db.t_cxc
                             where fc.c_cliente == item.c_cliente && fc.c_prestamo == item.c_prestamo
                                   && fc.c_tipocontrato == item.c_tipocontrato && fc.d_preanexo == item.d_preanexo
                             group fc by new { fc.c_factura, fc.c_prestamo, fc.d_preanexo } into g
                             select new LstReportes
                             {


                                 c_prestamo = fc.c_prestamo,

                                 n_cximp = g.Sum(x => x.n_cximp) >  0
                             }).ToList();

                ViewBag.model = fact2;

            }
            else if (item.isChecked == false)
            {

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Vista:

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<ArrendamientoWeb.Models.LstReportes>)ViewBag.model)
   {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.c_factura
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.f_cxfecven
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.n_cximp
            </td>

        </tr>
    }                    
</tbody>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En tu caso, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente filtrar antes de mandarlo al modelo, algo como `ViewBag.model = fact2.Where(x=> x.n_cximp>0)`. Prueba a ver si te vale asi...

Comment: El sum lo estas colocando en el resultado, que te arma la secuencia, deberia colocarlo en el where. Probaste iterar la consulta con un foreach y luego dentro un if para ver que sea mayor la suma?

Comment: cual es el sentido de usar esa linq dentro de un `foreach` ? porque en cada iteracion pisas el dato anterior del ViewBag. En la consulta sql que usaste de base no veo ningun where

Comment: Tu linq es el primer paso, luego ese resultado lo iteras en un foreach y realizas la condicion necesaria y llenas otra lista o pisas la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria evites el `foreach` ya que sino en cada iteracion deberias ir acumulando en una lista temporal

Por eso deberias ver si primero se puede filtrar todos los datos cruzando las listas para despues realizar el agrupado y suma

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewFact(List<LstReportes> model)
{
    var reportsChecked = model.Where(item=> item.isChecked);

    var fact1 = from fc in db.t_cxc
                from item in reportsChecked
                where fc.c_cliente == item.c_cliente 
                    && fc.c_prestamo == item.c_prestamo
                    && fc.c_tipocontrato == item.c_tipocontrato 
                    && fc.d_preanexo == item.d_preanexo
                select fc;

    var fact2 = (from fc in fact1
                 group fc by new { fc.c_factura, fc.c_prestamo, fc.d_preanexo } into g
                 where g.Sum(x => x.n_cximp) >  0
                 select new LstReportes
                 {
                     c_prestamo = fc.c_prestamo,
                     n_cximp = g.Sum(x => x.n_cximp)
                 }).ToList();


    ViewBag.model = fact2;

    return View();
}
```

Puedes realizar mas de una consulta de linq, usando el resultado de una como dato de entrada de la siguiente

Para el `having` usas un simple `where` pero sobre la variable `g` que es donde el `into` vuelca los datos que agrupa, por eso revisa puntualmente donde uso

```
where g.Sum(x => x.n_cximp) >  0
```